# Speed up rasterFromXYZ in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, raster, r-raster

I want to create a raster from a data.table with more than 100 million cells. Currently, I convert the `data.table` into a `data.frame` and then use the `rasterFromXYZ` function from the `raster` package. Unfortunately, the raster package is pretty slow and it takes 4-5 hours to create the raster.

Is there any package or already implemented solution to speed up this process? If not (and that's what I assume) I think the fastest solution should be to divide the big data.table to create many small rasters and then merge them at the end?

Comment: Maybe you could avoid creating a RasterLayer object, keep the data in its XYZ form and somehow work with that? What do you need the raster for?

Answer (score 0):

Is the data table ordered by rows and columns, and do you already know the geometry of your grid? If so then you can probably speed things up by creating a matrix of the right size and shape, and then creating a raster from that matrix and assigning the geometry to it.

Tiny example:

```
> d = data.frame(expand.grid(1:3,1:4),1:12)
> d
   Var1 Var2 X1.12
1     1    1     1
2     2    1     2
3     3    1     3
4     1    2     4
5     2    2     5
6     3    2     6
7     1    3     7
8     2    3     8
9     3    3     9
10    1    4    10
11    2    4    11
12    3    4    12
```

Using `rasterFromXYZ` gets me this:

```
> r1 = rasterFromXYZ(d)
> r1
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 4, 3, 12  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 0.5, 3.5, 0.5, 4.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : X1.12 
values     : 1, 12  (min, max)
```

Now some of what that function has to do is go through the X and Y coordinates to work out the grid geometry. But if you already know the extent and size, then you can also create the same raster in a couple of steps.

First make a matrix the right way round - for my ordering in `d` I need to fill the matrix by rows and flip the rows round to get the right order. If your XYZ table is ordered differently then you may need to do some other manipulation or it might be right. Note here I have to know in advance how many rows and columns there are:

```
r2 = raster(matrix(d[,3],ncol=3,nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)[4:1,])
```

then set the extent. Here I have to know in advance the extents, in this case half a cell wider than the min and max values, and my cell size is one unit:

```
extent(r2) = c(xmin=0.5, xmax=3.5, ymin=0.5, ymax=4.5)
```

Whatever you do is going to take a while on 100,000,000 cell rasters, so test on smaller examples with similar formats to your real data to see if its a win or not.